# logic apps http post multipart/formdata fails on image and forbidden

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Hoping some here can help me.

I am trying to post an image to my API via HTTP Post. When I post using the following code:

```
--TestLine
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Description"

test.txt
--TestLine
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ExternalDocumentType"

ATTACH_DD
--TestLine
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

test.txt
--TestLine
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FormattedAccount"

002.2020.00199659.001
--TestLine
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ModuleReference"

DD
--TestLine
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileUpload";filename=test.txt
Content-Type: text/plain

test upload
--TestLine--
```

it works for text files and image files BUT my images files are corrupted on the other end and cannot be opened.

I then read the following":

https://willpagenz.wordpress.com/2019/12/20/using-the-http-action-to-post-multipart-form-data-in-pow...

and tried coding it to that way:

```
{
  "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  "multipart": [
    {
      "body": {
        "$content": "test.txt"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"Description\""
      }
    },
    {
      "body": {
        "$content": "ATTACH_DD"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"ExternalDocumentType\""
      }
    },
    {
      "body": {
        "$content": "test.txt"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"Filename\""
      }
    },
    {
      "body": {
        "$content": "002.2020.00199662.001"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"FormattedAccount\""
      }
    },
    {
      "body": {
        "$content": "DD"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"ModuleReference\""
      }
    },
    {
      "body": {
        "$content": "test upload",
        "$content-type": "text/plain"
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"FileUpload\";filename=\"test.txt\""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but now I get forbidden and it can't even post through to my API

```
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2</center>
```

This is time sensitive. Does anyone have an answer.

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here